# PyQt QSplashScreen Image Resolution

Tags: python, pyqt5, splash-screen, pyqt6

I have a QSplashScreen with an image.The image looks fine when I open it. But When I run the splash, the picture has become full screen and blurred. I think it should be because the resolution of the picture is too high, but I don't know what to do.By the way, it's pyqt6. MacBook Pro 14（3024 × 1964）

[image: cover.png]

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys. argv)
    qp = QPixmap("./ICON/cover.png")
    splash = QSplashScreen(QPixmap(qp))
    splash.show()
    app.processEvents()
    myMainWindow = QMainWindow()
    myUi = Main_Window.Ui_MainWindow()
    myUi.setupUi(myMainWindow)
    splash.finish(myMainWindow)
    myMainWindow.show()
    sys. exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Use [`QPixmap.scaled()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled).

Comment: I tried qp = qp.scaled(750,520,QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio,QtCore.Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation), but it still lost clarity. If I change to scaled(1537,1041), the original size, it becomes to full screen again.

Comment: Scaling down obviously can cause precision loss due to the antialiasing algorithm. Please provide the original image and also specify the OS and possible system scaling (high dpi settings)

Comment: Original image uploaded.

Comment: So you're clearly on a high dpi device. Do some research about DPI scaling, and also carefully read about [High DPI on Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/highdpi.html). You'll be probably able to fix this by calling [`pixmap.setDevicePixelRatio(2.0)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#setDevicePixelRatio)

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem!